# Error username and password on Android login page with MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, authentication

I made a simple login page with MySQL and xampp. The problem is the login page will always work and redirect me to the other activity although i gave the wrong username or password. I'm not sure if the query is wrong or the code as i've triple check it and found no real solution. I'm using my android phone not the emulator. The LOGIN_URL **"192.168.43.231"** is my laptop's IP as i'm currently using my phone's data as hotspot. Thanks

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText usernameET, passwordET;
private Button login;
private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.43.231/Login/login.php";
public static  String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static  String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    usernameET = findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
    passwordET = findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
    login = findViewById(R.id.loginBTN);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String username = usernameET.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = passwordET.getText().toString().trim();

            if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Enter Valid Username & Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    boolean responseStatus = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
                                    if (responseStatus) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue =Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "select * from blast_user where username = '$username' and password =  '$password' ";

$check = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();
$response["success"]=false;

if($check){
$response["success"] = true;
}
else{
$response["success"]=false;
}

echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: You're using plain-text passwords! Do not do this! Use a hashing mechanism, such as the `password_*` functions

Comment: Also the query will return true even if there are no rows returned, so long as it was successfully executed. Check the number of rows instead after executing the query.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `if($check)` with `if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0)`.